# Auto add alt on images

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image, web

When I add

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#readerareaimg img').each(function(){
var filename = $img.attr('src')
$img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
$img.attr('alt', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
});
```

My website will generate alt and title tags automatically on images based on their file name, but I want to add any word before the file name.
For example file name is comic.jpg and I will display `alt="comic"`, but i want that alt to become `alt="read comic"`.

Can someone explain how to make this? Please, sir :3

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple case of concatenating the string when you set the alt attribute:

```
$img.attr('alt', 'read ' + filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

---

As for the number request from the comments, you can capture the index argument which is zero based, then +1 it to get 1-n.

```
$('#readerareaimg img').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('alt', 'comic naruto image ' + (index+1));
});
```

Comment: ty my friend :D i dont know anything about jquery and java, i just want to learn it! ty again, you save my website seo :v

Comment: do you know how to make auto number list 1-9 after name for each image list? for example i have 10 images than i want to make that alt > comic naruto image 1, comic naruto image 2 and other?

Answer (score 0):

You can use '+' sign in the where you put value of attribute.

```
$img.attr('alt', 'required word'+filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

or

```
$img.attr('alt',filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'))+'required word');
```